# Tensorflow 2.0 How to handle tf.Variable as Weight in __call__ function?

Tags: tensorflow

I made 'Decoder' layer to make Product Item Matrix in Tensorflow.
I've tried to initialize W, bias and make a calculation to get loss using some value.

```
class Decoder(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=len(counter), input_dim=300):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.trainer = Trainer(vec_dict)

        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(initial_value=w_init(shape=(units, input_dim), dtype='float32'), trainable=True)
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(initial_value=b_init(shape=(units,), dtype='float32'), trainable=True)

    def call(self, x_play, y_pos, y_neg):
        x = self.trainer(x_play)
        user_vector = x[..., tf.newaxis, :]

        wp = self.w.numpy()[y_pos]
        bp = self.b.numpy()[y_pos]
        pos_mul = tf.multiply(user_vector, wp)
        pos = tf.reduce_sum(pos_mul, axis=-1) + bp

        wn = self.w.numpy()[y_neg]
        bn = self.b.numpy()[y_neg]
        neg_mul = tf.multiply(user_vector, wn)
        neg = tf.reduce_sum(neg_mul, axis=-1) + bn

        tot = tf.sigmoid(tf.concat([pos, neg], axis=1))

        return tot
```

As you can see this, If I used '.numpy()', it can make me possible to get matrix which has the shape what I want to.

For instance, self.w has (10000, 300) shapes, and y_pos has (256, 100)
and self.w.numpy()[y_pos] has (256, 100, 300)

The problem is that if I ran this code for training, I got these kind of errors:

```
NotImplementedError: in converted code:

    <ipython-input-835-8d5f0b593979>:4 train_step  *
        predictions = model(x, y_pos, y_neg)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:847 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    <ipython-input-838-b9b896ea4fff>:64 call
        wp = self.w.numpy()[y_pos]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:579 numpy
        "numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.")

    NotImplementedError: numpy() is only available when eager execution is enabled.
```

Somebody else who let me know what's going on.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please do not roll this back again, David.